# Thunderbird with millions of gmail emails

Tags: thunderbird, gmail, imap, gmail-imap

I just tried using thunderbird hooked up to my gmail account using imap, which has at least 5 million emails in the account. Thunderbird is basically unresponsive, which isn't a huge surprise. I tried setting the option to only download mail that is 5 days old, and I changed the automatic download to not do any automatic downloading, but I suspect even just keeping an index of everything is too much. Is it possible to only have thunderbird deal with the last few days of email, and ignore everything older? I don't need anything older than that in thunderbird.

Comment: Which version of thunderbird? In which OS? Have you tried connecting a smaller account to see whether thunderbird works that case?

Comment: Thanks Máté, Thunderbird 68.2, Fedora 29, 16 core box, 64gb ram, ssd drives, lightly loaded. I have indeed tried a smaller account, and it was fine.

Comment: Then perhaps the mailbox is simply beyond the ability of Thunderbird to work with optimally. What you've given us so far certainly supports that basic idea.